# CSS is different after launching Developer Tools?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm having a weird problem right now.

I'm trying to iron out a CSS bug in Chrome, but whenever I enter Developer Tools the bug is mysteriously fixed.

How would you go about a situation like this?

And why is the rendering engine playing tricks on me? ;)

Comment: Could yo provide a code example, on jsfiddel for example? Maybe the change is related to the recaluclated height of the viewport when opening the dev tools, is the bug also present when starting the dev tools in a separate window?

Comment: @Jona Yep, that was my initial thought as well, that it was some kind of absolute positioning issue – but the bug is still there when I launch dev tools in another window.

Comment: I'm reluctant to post my example here, due to corporate secrecy illuminati-bizzle, but I will see if I can get around to do a generic example.

Comment: There is not much that can be done here without seeing some live example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [the bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=102046) and it was reported number of times.
It was fixed 6 day ago.
Please wait for the next version of Dev channel build.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with firefox instead.. The developers toolbar works well, and also firebug for firefox is way better for debugging :)